# Как разрешить в input вводить только один русский символ и работало Ctrl + Z

Tags: javascript, события

Как мне сделать так, чтобы работало сочетание клавиш `Ctrl` + `Z`, после того, как я ввёл русский символ?
Сейчас у меня это сочетание клавиш не убирает введенный символ, если после ввода русского символа попробовать ввести любой другой символ

```js
edit.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.value.match(/[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+/)) {
    e.target.value = '';
  }
  if (e.target.value.length > 1) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value[0];
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="edit" placeholder="Введите букву!">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если стоит русская раскладка, то 'я'?

```js
let edit = document.getElementById('edit');

edit.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.value.match(/[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+/)) {
    e.target.value = '';
  }
  if (e.target.value.length > 1) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value[0];
  }
});

edit.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if ((e.key == 'я' || e.key == 'Я' || e.key == 'z' || e.key == 'Z') && e.ctrlKey) {
    e.preventDefault()
    edit.value = edit.value.slice(0, -1);
    // Если один символ, то можно:
    // edit.value = '';
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="edit" placeholder="Введите букву!">
```

Comment: у меня в поле можно ввести строго только один символ, больше нельзя

Comment: Ввел один, а потом? Следующие?

Comment: нет, всё, больше ничего нельзя. У меня игра, в которой ты отгадываешь букву и можно ввести только одну букву

Comment: Что может быть проще чем вернуть твой код на место! Главное Ctrl+z устраивает?

Comment: да, всё классно работает!